# Retrieve Value from Field in Laravel Cast Array

Tags: laravel, casting

I have a table named `settings`, in it, there are several columns, `id`,`company_id`, `key`, `value`.

In my Laravel model for Setting, I have the following cast:

```
protected $casts = [
    'value' => 'array',
];
```

But when I go to retrieve data that has been stored, I can't.

For example, I have a record with the following `value`: `"{\"default_remit_address\":\"2395\"}"`

And when I go to retrieve the record in a Blade, it does pull it up correctly, but I'm not sure how to grab a specific value from the `value` field (like default_remit_address).

If I print the return `"{{$settings->value}}"` directly in the Blade, this is what I get:

`{"default_remit_address":"2395"}`

So how can I go one level deeper?

Answer (score 0):

As this json object is being cast to an `Array`, you can just use regular array syntax to access it's contents.

```
$default_remit_address = Settings::find(1)->value['default_remit_address'];
```

or in your blade template

```
{{ $settings->value['default_remit_address'] }}
```

Comment: If I do it like above, I get the following error: Illegal string offset 'default_remit_address' , can you suggest what I might be missing?

Comment: Hmm, is the value column created by the migration using `$table->json('value')`? I am suspicious because of the encoding you have in your string `"{\"default_remit_address\":\"2395\"}"`. Similar values in my local database do not contain the the backslashes (maybe you are double encoding at some point when storing?)